# Issues installing python package on windows

Tags: python, gcc, g++, rocksdb

I'm trying to install [python-rocksdb](https://python-rocksdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) on a windows 10 machine and I'm coming across some issues with the install.

I have successfully installed [rocksdb](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/INSTALL.md) first using the vcpkg method.

When running `pip install python-rocksdb` I get the following error:

```
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wextra'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

Looking around suggested attempting to install with GCC or G++, so I downloaded cygwin and then attempted to install the python package using
`pip install --global-option build_ext --global-option --compiler=cygwin python-rocksdb` which yielded the following error:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option â€˜-mcygwinâ€™
error: command 'C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

[This post](https://github.com/twmht/python-rocksdb/issues/66#issuecomment-723466228) seems to suggest that you need to use g++ specifically, but it looks like the cygwin command is defaulting to gcc.

Just note that I'm not using the virtual env with python.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried an alternative such as `rocksdict`?

Comment: I would, except I need to use this with the faust-streaming package, and that requires `python-rocksdb`. I don't use it directly. If you know how to make them compatible, let me know.

Comment: No idea, but this one doesn't look easy to build on Windows.

Comment: I know. While the production machine is Linux (Centos 8 stream), I only have access to a Windows machine for development. Using a VM or something like virtual box isn't really useful for full development due to lag, so I'm looking for a Windows solution.

Comment: What about Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

Comment: Too cumbersome for me, but a good solution suggestion.

Comment: Oooo... so firstly, the original package is no longer maintained, so the new package to install is `faust-streaming-rocksdb`. Still not quite installing on windows, but I'm getting closer

Comment: I would definitely investigate the WSL route as it's native code (no VM) so there is little to no performance impact. It's basically cygwin on steroids.